# Template Based : Load Dynamic Content in Django Through Ajax using Dynamic URL Pattern based on Slug

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x

Facing issues for loading (including) dynamic content through a template tag "include" or from 'Ajax' based Loading.

As said [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024220/how-can-i-put-a-block-of-dynamically-generated-content-into-a-django-template), There are three ways to do... But still having issues

Working on Django 2.1.3, Python 3.6...

I have tried two ways:
1. Using "Include" Tag
2. By Loading Through Ajax

#### Python

views.py

```
def equity(request,symbol):

    """
    some code
    """

    context_all = {
    'template_Name': ('/autoRefreshEqu/{}/').format(symbol)
        }
    template = loader.get_template('equity/equity.html')
    response_body = template.render(context_all,request)
    return HttpResponse(response_body)

def autoRefreshEqu(request,symbol):

    """
    code for generating context
    """

    context_all = {
    'quote':quote,
    'changeQuote':changeQuote,
    'lastPrice': x['data'][0]['change'],
    'change':x['data'][0]['change'],
    'pChange':x['data'][0]['pChange'],
    'lastUpdateTime': x['lastUpdateTime'],

    }

template = loader.get_template('equity/autorefequ.html')
response_body = template.render(context_all,request)
return HttpResponse(response_body)
```

urls.py

```
path('autoRefreshEqu/<slug:symbol>/',views.autoRefreshEqu, name="autoRefreshEqu"),

path('equity/<slug:symbol>/',views.equity, name="equity"),
```

#### HTML Section

equity/equity.html

Reference Provided for Comment With Nos. as Guidance in Description.

```
<!-- Code Persists + Load Static + Humanize + Extends base.html, all working well -->

<!-- Reference for 2. -->
<script>$("#autoupdate").load("{% url template_Name %}");</script>

<div id="autoupdate">

<!-- Reference for 1. -->
{include template_Name} 

<!-- Load The Content Generated by autoRefreshEqu/<slug:symbol>/ -->
</div>
```

equity/autorefequ.html

```
{% load humanize %}
{% load static %}
<div class="card text-center">
<div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="alignleft">Current Price</h2>
    <p class="alignright"><label class="switch"> <input type="checkbox" > <span class="slider"></span></label></p>
    <!--p class="alignright"><label class="switch"> <input type="checkbox" checked> <span class="slider"></span></label></p-->
</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <!--h5 class="card-title"></h5-->
  <p class="card-text">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
                {% if changeQuote > 0 %}
                      <td class="m" rowspan="2" style="color:green">
                         <strong style="font-size: 40px;">
                            <center>₹ {{lastPrice |intcomma}} </center>
                         </strong> 
                         <center><img src="{% static "/images/arrow_ticker_up.gif" %}">&nbsp;₹ {{change |intcomma}} ({{pChange |intcomma}} %)</center>
                      </td>
                      {% else %}
                      <td class="m" rowspan="2" style="color:red">
                         <strong style="font-size: 40px;">
                            <center>₹ {{lastPrice |intcomma}} </center>
                         </strong>
                         <center><img src="{% static "/images/arrow_ticker_down.gif" %}">&nbsp;₹ {{change |intcomma}} ({{pChange |intcomma}} %)</center>
                      </td>
                      {% endif %}
             </table>
</div>
<div class="card-footer text-muted">
    <p class="alignleft">Last Updated at {{lastUpdateTime}} <p class="alignright"> <span class="reload"><a href="#">↻</a></span></p>
</div>
```

#### Traceback

```
[05/Feb/2019 14:07:56] "GET /quoteAPI/v1/EICHERMOT HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[05/Feb/2019 14:07:58] "GET /quoteAPI/v1/EICHERMOT/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1903
[05/Feb/2019 14:07:58] "GET /autoRefreshEqu/EICHERMOT/ HTTP/1.1" 200 792
[05/Feb/2019 14:08:16] "GET /quoteAPI/v1/EICHERMOT HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[05/Feb/2019 14:08:18] "GET /quoteAPI/v1/EICHERMOT/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1903
[05/Feb/2019 14:08:18] "GET /quoteAPI/v1/EICHERMOT HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[05/Feb/2019 14:08:20] "GET /quoteAPI/v1/EICHERMOT/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1903
Internal Server Error: /equity/EICHERMOT/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\frontend\ticker\views.py", line 119, in equity
response_body = template.render(context_all,request)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 442, in render
url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
 File "C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\New F 3\project\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '/autoRefreshEqu/EICHERMOT/' not found. '/autoRefreshEqu/EICHERMOT/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Suppose, I'm Calling URL as 

 /equity/EICHERMOT/ 
then the template should call out

 /autoRefreshEqu/EICHERMOT/ 
and render to the main equity template.

The div having id=autoupdate should have all the context generated by autoRefreshEqu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're passing the URL through the `{% url %}` tag. That's for taking a URL pattern name and converting it to a URL. You already have a fully-formed URL, so you can just use it directly:

```
<script>$("#autoupdate").load("{{ template_Name }}");</script>
```

Of course, that doesn't make this a good way to do things. You *should* be using `{% url %}` rather than hard-coding your URL in the view. Remove that `template_Name` variable and instead pass `symbol`; then, in the template:

```
<script>$("#autoupdate").load("{% url "autoRefreshEqu" symbol=symbol %}");</script>
```

Comment: It Works, but the content it should load isn't showing up.

Comment: <script>
      $.ajax({
       url: "{% url 'autoRefreshEqu' symbol=symbol %}",
       success: function(data) {
   $('#autoupdate').html(data);
   }
  });
  </script>  : Is this method ok to work with ?